# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError error on linux

Tags: java, linux

I have a third party java application called MITIE that I am currently testing to potentially integrate it into a java project. I have compiled the code and can run it using the following script (run.sh):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/MITIE/mitielib
export CLASSPATH=/opt/MITIE/mitielib/javamitie.jar:.

javac NerExample.java
java NerExample
```

Everything runs fine. What I want to do is be able put the export commands in my ~/.bashrc so I can run this library within a java project or just type java NerExample on the command line and not have to worry about setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or CLASSPATH.

I added the two export statements to my ~/.bashrc profile and then removed them from the script and I get the error:

```
Native code library failed to load. 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no javamitie in java.library.path
```

If I put the export statements back into the script it works. My question is, is it possible to set these globally on my system?

Comment: What distribution are you using? Also, did you logout and log back in after you modified your `.bashrc`?

Comment: I am using CentOS, I did not log out, but I did do source ~/.bashrc, I also just logged out and logged back in and it still does not work.

Comment: If you did that, and you have the `export`(s) as above then it should be identical to running the `export`(s) in your other script... something doesn't add up here. Is it a new `.bashrc` and have you made it executable?

Comment: Are the new export statements at the end of the `.bashrc`? Is it possible you override it with something else later? (It might be better practice to use it like this: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/MITIE/mitielib`)

Comment: That was the issue. I was rewriting it later. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath can be extended in /etc/profile
export classpath=$CLASSPATH:/add/to/classpath. Sorry I am typing on my phone so you need to correct that.
aps.

Your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not necessary if you add a line to /etc/ld.so.conf then sudo ldconfig.